# SSIS Project Deployment Model: How to find a specific object (SqlServer2012)

Tags: ssis-2012

I'm having an issue related to find all references for one column used in my project, which has over 25 SSIS Packages (.dtsx files). The problem started when I had to change the structure for several columns from varchar(xxx) to varchar (yyy) and those columns not only existed on actual databases but also could been found in many statements (as temporary tables), spread out to all existing packages (hope It makes sense). All I need is to find at least what .dtsx package has in it those columns (as in one .dtsx package I have lots of objects).
  I was able to find something [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1531885-364-1.aspx) on this topic, but is for SQL 2010 and I cannot apply it to my server.
  Any hints on how to find lets say all objects where the column "ColumnA" is referenced, in one SSIS Project ?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a package (not project!) name, click view code. CTRL+F and enter the name of your column. Search the entire solution.

Comment: thanks for your effort to read my post and to write something back, but what you implied cannot help anyone...I have over 25  dtsx packages and I have to search for more than 200 coluns. Let say I only have 1 column. If I do what you wrote, I will find all references that match the column's name, even if they are name for packages and other type of objects...